# NLTK path_similarity is giving ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, nltk

I am currently doing a coursera assignment with NLTK to find Path_similarity between two documents, but got stuck.

```
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import pandas as pd

nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('punkt')

def convert_tag(tag):
    """Convert the tag given by nltk.pos_tag to the tag used by wordnet.synsets"""
    
    tag_dict = {'N': 'n', 'J': 'a', 'R': 'r', 'V': 'v'}
    try:
        return tag_dict[tag[0]]
    except KeyError:
        return None


def doc_to_synsets(doc):
    """
    Returns a list of synsets in document.

    Tokenizes and tags the words in the document doc.
    Then finds the first synset for each word/tag combination.
    If a synset is not found for that combination it is skipped.

    Args:
        doc: string to be converted

    Returns:
        list of synsets

    Example:
        doc_to_synsets('Fish are nvqjp friends.')
        Out: [Synset('fish.n.01'), Synset('be.v.01'), Synset('friend.n.01')]
    """
    tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(doc)
    tokens=nltk.pos_tag(syn)
    
    updated_pos=[convert_tag(x[1]) for x in tokens]
    
    tokens=[(tokens[x][0],updated_pos[x]) for x in range(len(tokens))]
    
    
    
    ds=[wn.synsets(tokens[x][0],pos=tokens[x][1]) for x in range(len(tokens))]
    ds1=[]
    for x in range(len(tokens)):
        try:
            ds1.append(ds[x][0])
        except:
            continue
    return ds1
def similarity_score(s1, s2):
    """
    Calculate the normalized similarity score of s1 onto s2

    For each synset in s1, finds the synset in s2 with the largest similarity value.
    Sum of all of the largest similarity values and normalize this value by dividing it by the
    number of largest similarity values found.

    Args:
        s1, s2: list of synsets from doc_to_synsets

    Returns:
        normalized similarity score of s1 onto s2

    Example:
        synsets1 = doc_to_synsets('I like cats')
        synsets2 = doc_to_synsets('I like dogs')
        similarity_score(synsets1, synsets2)
        Out: 0.73333333333333339
    """
    maxscore=[]
    for x in s1:
        dis=[]
        for y in s2:
            dis.append(x.path_similarity(y))
            dis=[z for z in dis if z!=None]
        maxscore.append(max(dis))
    return sum(maxscore)/len(maxscore)
    
    
def document_path_similarity(doc1,doc2):
    """Finds the symmetrical similarity between doc1 and doc2"""

    synsets1 = doc_to_synsets(doc1)
    synsets2 = doc_to_synsets(doc2)

    return (similarity_score(synsets1, synsets2)+similarity_score(synsets2, synsets1))/ 2

 #This is a test Function to check wether the above funtion is correct or not
def test_document_path_similarity():
    doc1 = 'This is a function to test document_path_similarity.'
    doc2 = 'Use this function to see if your code in doc_to_synsets \
    and similarity_score is correct!'
    return document_path_similarity(doc1, doc2)
```

My issue is that this test funciton instead of returning a float value & it is giving This ValueError:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-6c20d7dcffc6> in <module>()
----> 1 test_document_path_similarity()

<ipython-input-60-9639d05f12da> in test_document_path_similarity()
      2     doc1 = 'This is a function to test document_path_similarity.'
      3     doc2 = 'Use this function to see if your code in doc_to_synsets     and similarity_score is correct!'
----> 4     return document_path_similarity(doc1, doc2)

<ipython-input-59-849dd19f38dc> in document_path_similarity(doc1, doc2)
     89     synsets2 = doc_to_synsets(doc2)
     90 
---> 91     return (similarity_score(synsets1, synsets2)+similarity_score(synsets2, synsets1))/ 2

<ipython-input-59-849dd19f38dc> in similarity_score(s1, s2)
     79             dis.append(x.path_similarity(y))
     80             dis=[z for z in dis if z!=None]
---> 81         maxscore.append(max(dis))
     82     return sum(maxscore)/len(maxscore)
     83 

ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

This is basically because the path similarity beween synsets2[-1] and every synset of synsets1 is givng a None value.
But it should not be like this according to the instructions ,I tried for so much time but could'nt figure out how to avoid this and get a float value.

As the instructors may take days to respond,I came here for help,Please look into this,if you could.
edit:these are the synsets2 and synsets1.

```
synsets2=[Synset('use.v.01'),
  Synset('function.n.01'),
  Synset('see.v.01'),
  Synset('code.n.01'),
  Synset('inch.n.01'),
  Synset('be.v.01'),
  Synset('correct.a.01')],


synsets1=[Synset('be.v.01'),
  Synset('angstrom.n.01'),
  Synset('function.n.01'),
  Synset('test.v.01')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good only you need to add this statement: if(dis):
Because you want maxscore.append(max(dis)) will only be calculated when "dis" has a value otherwise it will not be considered.

So the part of your code that you need to modify will look like this:

```html
maxscore=[]
for x in s1:
    dis=[]
    for y in s2:
        dis.append(x.path_similarity(y))
        dis=[z for z in dis if z!=None]
    if(dis):
        maxscore.append(max(dis))
return sum(maxscore)/len(maxscore)
```